# VueJS left menu list that updates main content panel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `VueJS` application where I have the need to create a component that will have a left menu and a main content like the following image:

[image]

Once the view is loaded, on `create method` I will load `left menu json` and the `items content json`. By that time no item is going to be rendered in the main content.

Once the user selects an item from the left menu, the `json` for the items content is going to be filtered so that the main component renders the squares (each item component that is actually separate component).

My question here is about how many components should I build?

I guess I will have to create a component container that will hold the `left menu component` and the `right component`. Then right component will have the header and a `v-for` element that will render each of the `item component`. Is that the way to go?

> Any advice?

Comment: 1. Create it in one component and break it out as you get annoyed! 2. Your count is probably fine. 3. You could create left menu component that actually implements a main content with item-content rather than breaking the link  E.g. `Left item -> main content -> item -> item content` rather than `Left Menu -> Item` AND `main content -> main content -> item -> item-content`

Comment: So you mean that 3. is create a left menu component and in side this template have the HTML that renders the main content and items?

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing really stopping you from doing either method. I'm not sure of the benefits besides the left-menu would be able to pass `props` down through all the components.  I imagine when you click a link in the menu you're just going to set the "item" you want to show, and then the sub component should handle loading the rest of the data. Whether you do that as a prop or simply `data` in the main app doesn't really matter...

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one container component that lays out all three areas using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Then you can have a component for each area: left-menu, header-thing, and main-content.

There's a bit of a learning curve with grid layout, but it's *immensely* useful. Modern browsers [support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), but not IE.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    leftMenu: {
      template: '#left-menu-template'
    },
    mainContent: {
      template: '#main-content-template'
    },
    headerThing: {
      template: '<div class="header-thing"><div>one</div><div>two</div></div>'
    }
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'lm h'
    'lm mc'
  ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-thing {
  background-color: #eef;
  grid-area: h;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 0.7em;
  grid-gap: 1.4em;
}

.left-menu {
  background-color: #efe;
  grid-area: lm;
  padding: 0.7em;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: #fee;
  grid-area: mc;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8em, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.content-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 2em 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <header-thing></header-thing>
  <left-menu></left-menu>
  <main-content></main-content>
</div>

<template id="left-menu-template">
  <nav class="left-menu">
    <div>First item</div>
    <div>Second item</div>
  </nav>
</template>

<template id="main-content-template">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-item">item</div>
    <div class="content-item">another</div>
    <div class="content-item">another</div>
    <div class="content-item">more</div>
    <div class="content-item">still more</div>
    <div class="content-item">another</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Woow Very amazing!!.. Thanks a lot